# Internal speakers and internal mic not working

Tags: 18.04, sound

After fixing a problem with the internal mic by running the pavucontrol command to unlock controls and turn right speaker all the way to zero, the speakers stopped working the next time i restarted the computer (lenovo idea pad). All the controls indicate that the sound is on, but there is no sound on any applications.

Answer (score 0):

So everything is working now. It was a problem of controls and settings. I played around with it, choosing OFF for one of the profile options and then speakers worked again. Also for the mic I turned the right speaker to zero and the left down to 30% and the sound is fine now. But I still don't understand what the PROFILE is on the audio settings and why it has to be off, or what the different options mean:
bult-in audio analogue stereo
and
digital stereo HDMI output